# How to get the coordinates of the country from overpass turbo

Tags: reactjs, json, leaflet, mern

I'm working on a project using MERN technologies. In this project I decided to integrate an interactive map from Leaflet. I briefly explain how it works. Basically, there is this React component that takes the data of each country from a JSON file, which has this structure:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ADMIN": "Aruba", "ISO_A3": "ARU" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -69.996937628999916, 12.577582098000036 ],
```

Of course, the coordinates continue. In practice, what happens? I have slightly different requirements in this map than in a normal map. For example, I need the UK to be divided and its constituent states, such as Scotland, Wales, England and Northern Ireland, to be shown on the map. You have to believe me, I've searched on Internet, I've asked ChatGPT, but nothing. I can't find a JSON file that can give me the exact borders of Scotland or the other states.
Luckily, I found this site: 'https://overpass-turbo.eu/#'. What does it do? By sending a query, it returns the coordinates in JSON format of a given country. For example, this is an example of a query that returns me the Czech Republic.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:Czechia}}->.searchArea;
(
  relation["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="7"](area.searchArea);
);

// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

As I said before, I searched the Internet for JSON coordinates for Scotland and also tried to ask ChatGPT for them manually. I'm expecting someone to be able to tell me how to find these coordinates, possibly from the site I wrote above, by pointing me to a working query. And yes, I have asked ChatGPT for the queries for Scotland, but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert shapefile to json(just google country shapefile) online/QGIS/ArcGIS [here's one](https://maps.princeton.edu/catalog/stanford-pc593vv9067). Once you have access to json/geojson data you can use 'shpjs' to display polygon shapefile over map.